# Importing packages in CQ5

Tags: aem, jcr, crx

My program to creates a jcr package(zip file), this package contains the node structure that can be imported in CQ5 crx package manager. While many nodes are imported successfully, there are certain nodes which failed to import content and i can see only one line in CQ5 error logs

```
com.day.jcr.vault.fs.impl.io.GenericArtifactHandler Error while parsing jcr_root/content/abc/foo/bar/.content.xml: org.xml.sax.SAXException
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
com.day.jcr.vault.fs.io.Importer E /content/abc/foo/bar (org.xml.sax.SAXException java.lang.IllegalArgumentException)
```

Is there a way to validate a jcr package before installing in CQ5 crx package manager? or increase the log level so I can see the details in the error?

Any help is appreciated, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The exception hints at a parse error in your XML file.  Potentially, your build script can "test" each XML file to make sure it passes validation before building the package.